# Selecting item dynamically added to Menu Item List

Tags: vb.net, menuitem

I'm using the below loop to add items to a Menu Item Strip dynamically on program load

```
For Each specs In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(My.Settings.SpecsLoc, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.pdf*")  
        SpecsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(IO.Path.GetFileName(specs))
    Next
```

This will populate the Menu item with, on average, 20 items. I've been searching on how to now open the files from the list.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor can also take an event handler, so you can just add it like this:

```
SpecsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(IO.Path.GetFileName(specs), _
                                         Nothing, _
                                         Sub()
                                           Process.Start(specs)
                                         End Sub)
```